# How to make xml file in mac?

Tags: xml, api, testing

I am trying to make XML file for giving path in eclipse

and I can make XML file 
by opening textedit in Mac 
past my XML  data 
change to plain text 
and then give .XML extension
 its create file doesn't work ? and its look like image

any suggestion on this or any other way ? after creating xml file.

[image]

Comment: how are you viewing your xml file ? In Safari ? 
what happens when you open your created xml file in TextEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer**

Your xml file is already fine. Problem is that Safari will not show raw xml by default . You can view xml in Safari by opening **Show Web Inspector** option from **Develop** menu. You may need to enable develop menu from advanced options
(if not already enabled)

**Reference:**https://uglyduckling.nl/blog/software/using-safari-to-view-xml-files/

**Old Answer**

You can create xml files directly in Eclipse.

To create a new XML file, complete the following steps:

1. Create a project to contain the XML file if one does not exist already.
2. In the workbench, click File > New > Other and select XML > XML. Click Next.
3. Select the project or folder that will contain the XML file.
4. In the File name field, type the name of the XML file and click Next. The name of your XML file must end in .xml.
   5.Select the Create XML file from an XML template radio button and click Next..
5. Optional: You may choose to view and edit the XML templates that will be used in your new XML file.
6. Click Finish.

**Reference:**
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftcretxml.html